# timestamp difference in Kibana

Tags: sql, oracle, logstash, kibana, kibana-5

I have two fields as part of a SQL query coming to our ELK cluster:

```
"TO_TIME": "22-FEB-17 10.37.21.000000000 AM",
"FROM_TIME": "22-FEB-17 10.34.37.000000000 AM"
```

Is there a way to get the time difference between this fields (in this case 2 minutes 44 sec.) in each log message and display it through Kibana?

If this does not work Oracle SQL query would work too

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is an Oracle answer.  Oracle does not have a datediff function, but you can use math.   The concept is.

```
to_time - from_time = a floating point number
The integer portion of that number represents days.
The decimal portion represents partial days.  In other words, 1.5 would represent 36 hours.
```

Now all you have to do is apply that concept to your requirements.

Comment: Example dates are xhown with fractional seconds, so it mighr be TIMESTAMP value rather than DATE In this case the result is not a float number but an INTERVAL data value.